# XPath and XPathSelectElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml

```
<root>
   <databases>
      <db1 name="Name1" />
      <db2 name="Name2" server="myserver" />
      <db3 name="Name3" />
   </databases>
<root>
```

I've tried everything to read the name of the db2 (="Name2") with all possible combinations of XPath queries, but never get the expected result.

My Code so far:

```
var query = "root/databases/db2.. "; // here I've tried everything 
var doc = XDocument.Load("myconfig.xml");
var dbName =  doc.XPathSelectElement(query);
```

What's the correct query to get my "Name2" (the value of the Attribute) ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean `get my "Name2"`?  Do you want the element instance, the attribute instance, or the value of that attribute?

Comment: I want the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var dbName = doc.XPathSelectElement("root/databases/db2").Attribute("name");
```

Comment: oh. that means i can't put the attribute in the xpath query?

Comment: `XPathSelectElement` returns node

Comment: Note that since XPathSelectElement is an extension method, it requires the following using statement: `using System.Xml.XPath;`

Comment: Additional note that may help.  To get the actual name of the database "Name2" you will need to get the value of the attribute:

var dbName = doc.XPathSelectElement("root/databases/db2").Attribute("name").Value;

Answer (score 38):

The [XPathSelectElement method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083.aspx) can only be used to select elements, not attributes.

For attributes, you need to use the more general [XPathEvaluate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675.aspx):

```
var result = ((IEnumerable<object>)doc.XPathEvaluate("root/databases/db2/@name"))
                                      .OfType<XAttribute>()
                                      .Single()
                                      .Value;

// result == "Name2"
```

Comment: This lets you skip the parsing if you get an xpath.  Calling XPathEvaluate().Single() lets you test if you get an XElement or an XAttribute and keep going.

Answer (score 16):

To get the value (`Name2`) of the `name` attribute, of the `db2` element, try this:

```
    var query = "root/databases/db2";
    var doc = XDocument.Load("myconfig.xml");
    var dbElement = doc.XPathSelectElement(query);
    Console.WriteLine(dbElement.Attribute("name").Value);
```

If you don't know the name of the element (`db2`), but do know that it has a `server` attribute, try this:

```
    var query = "root/databases/*[@server]";
    var doc = XDocument.Load("myconfig.xml");
    var dbElement = doc.XPathSelectElement(query);
    Console.WriteLine(dbElement.Attribute("name").Value);
```

If you want to do the same thing as the previous example, but there are multiple elements with a `server` attribute, and you want to pick between those, try this:

```
    var query = "root/databases/*[@server='myserver']";
    var doc = XDocument.Load("myconfig.xml");
    var dbElement = doc.XPathSelectElement(query);
    Console.WriteLine(dbElement.Attribute("name").Value);
```