# XPath to fetch nodes in descending order of attribute value

Tags: performance, linq, sorting, xpath, xmldocument

I have an XML node structure in below format

```
<comments>
  <comment lastupdated='12/08/2014:08:08:08' moderate='false'>
     <id>user1</id>
     <message>some message</message>
     <replies>
         <comment moderate='false'>
            <id>user2</id>
            <message>some other message</message>
         </comment>
     </replies>
   </comment>
  <comment lastupdated='13/08/2014:12:08:40' moderate='false'>
     <id>user3</id>
     <message>some message</message>
     <replies>
         <comment moderate='false'>
            <id>user1</id>
            <message>some other message</message>
         </comment>
     </replies>
   </comment>
 </comments>
```

I found this XML to LINQ solution [XMLdocument Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107097/xmldocument-sort) want to know if this can be also achieved through XPath so that I don't need to load a new assembly. Also I am little confused with attributes and child nodes? in terms of performance which one is better? fetch by attribute value or child node?

**Update 1**

The solution suggested by @Timothy in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344737/sorting-xml-nodes-based-on-datetime-attribute-c-xpath?rq=1) seems promising

```
var sortedItems = myDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item").OfType<XmlElement>()
.OrderBy(item => DateTime.ParseExact(item.GetAttribute("sTime"), "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `XDocument.XPathSelectElements` method? see this question:  [XPath and XPathSelectElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289784/xpath-and-xpathselectelement)

Be aware that you can not select attributes directly. I'm not sure how performant this method is, you can always just iterate through the tree yourself though.